# Model Binding string fields in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

OK I am having a problem with MVC where I have controllers/views attached to multiple models which contain Protected Internal Sets for strings. When these objects are being created I need the strings to be able to be set. Having said that I am having problems understanding ModelBinding to accomplish this. I have attached a very basic set up for the ModelBinder but don't know where to go from here:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles binding for the string variables
/// </summary>
public class ActionResultModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder, IModelBinder, ITypedModelBinder
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type that this model binder's associated with
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The type that this model binder's associated with.
    /// </value>
    public Type AssociatedType
    {
        get
        {
           return typeof(string);
        }
    }

    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Binds the model by using the specified controller context and binding context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The context within which the controller operates. The context information includes the controller, HTTP content, request context, and route data.</param>
    /// <param name="bindingContext">The context within which the model is bound. The context includes information such as the model object, model name, model type, property filter, and value provider.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The bound object.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="bindingContext "/>parameter is null.</exception>
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var boundValue = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        return bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the specified property by using the specified controller context, binding context, and property value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The context within which the controller operates. The context information includes the controller, HTTP content, request context, and route data.</param>
    /// <param name="bindingContext">The context within which the model is bound. The context includes information such as the model object, model name, model type, property filter, and value provider.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyDescriptor">Describes a property to be set. The descriptor provides information such as the component type, property type, and property value. It also provides methods to get or set the property value.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to set for the property.</param>
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var stringVal = value as string;
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me explain.

You want to bind a model so first you need to return that model in

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
```

here is an example of custom binder to bind a model called FacebookGroupViewModel:

```
public class FacebookGroupViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var model = new FacebookGroupViewModel();
            if(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys.Contains("Friends"))
            {
                var friends = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Friends"].Split(',');
                foreach (var friend in friends)
                {
                    model.FacebookFriendIds.Add(friend);
                }


 }
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Here you can see that I  grab a value from a form :

```
controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Friends"]
```

but you can grab the value from QueryString or whatever you want as you have HttpContext here. Debug and have a look at all the property you have to find out more.

Finally you need to set up this binder and associate it to your model in the global.asax by doing this way.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(FacebookGroupViewModel),new FacebookGroupViewModelBinder());
```

In the application start method.

Then just use Imagine this my Controller is like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostFriend(FacebookGroupViewModel model)
{
//here your model is binded by your custom model ready to use.
}
```

Job done, let me know if you have more question about this.

**More information that you don't really need** :

```
 protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
```

Allow you to use default binder behavior and override some property like you were doing only string, but for this you need to use the original bindModel method.(eg base.BindModel)